# Getting Error message: Value is undefined in angular 6 application

Tags: node.js, npm, angular6, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using mean stack. There I have an input field which gives a color picker(ngx color picker). I want to save the picked color in the mongo db.
Here is my html.

```
<div class="form group">
  Movement Box:
 <input type="text" nbInput [(colorPicker)]="colorMovementBox" [style.background]="colorMovementBox" name="movementBox" color-picker-model="colorMovementBox" (colorPickerChange)="onChangeColor($event)" />
</div>
```

These are relavant methods in component.ts file

```
saveRDAColorValue(rdaColor: NgForm) {
    console.log("color of rda" + rdaColor.value.colorMovementBox);
    if (rdaColor.value.colorMovementBox != "" && rdaColor.value.colorMovementBox != null) {
      this.rdaColorService.saveRdaColor(rdaColor.value.colorMovementBox).subscribe(res => {
        console.log("save in ts file");
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }

public onChangeColor(color: string): Cmyk {
    const hsva = this.cpService.stringToHsva(color);
    const rgba = this.cpService.hsvaToRgba(hsva);
    console.log(color);
    console.log(rgba);
    return this.cpService.rgbaToCmyk(rgba);
  }
```

This is routes

```
router.post('/save', (req, res)=>{
    var rdaColor = new rdaColor(
        {
            movementBox: req.body.colorMovementBox,
        }
    );
    rdaColor.save((err,doc)=> {
    if(!err){
        res.send(doc);}
        else{
            console.log(err);
        }
        });
});
```

When I run the application color value is not saved in the database. When I debug, it shows value of 'rdaColor.value.colorMovementBox' as 'undefined'. Does anyone has a suggestion?